# Can there be a server directly behind a gTLD?

Tags: dns, tld

Let's suppose a compagny applied for and was granted the managmeent of the ".foo" domains

It can issue then domain like bar.foo, bip.foo, anything.foo, etc

But can there be a server pointed by just the gTLD, meaning for exemple a web page at http://foo/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes. But the contract you have to sign with ICANN in order to get a gTLD forbids it. So in practice, no.